# The Taylors expansions of Butcher's B-series (for Runge-Kutta order conditions)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, runge-kutta-methods

In the Butchher's [book](http://62.182.86.140/main/2861000/ac6bbddfe7a1dc3e31892af53eb4306b/Butcher%2C%20J%20C%20-%20Numerical%20Methods%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations-Wiley%20%282016%29.pdf)  numerical methods for ODE I do not understand in the proof how do we obtain the coefficient in the formula $311d$ at $F(t)(y(x_0))h^{|t|}$ from $$\frac{1}{t!}\xi^{|t|}$$ where $t=[t_1t_2...t_k]$

[image]

**EDIT Lemma 310B**

[image]

Comment: @AnneBauval A difficult pages for me. I have added the Lemma 310 B for your reference. I'm not sure how to apply it. Coul you please direct me a bit more concretely ?

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, I haven't saved it. Can you see it now, has it helped ?

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your interest. I have written everything into my original question. It also contains the full pdf of the book. Please see this: In the Butchher's [book](http://62.182.86.140/main/2861000/ac6bbddfe7a1dc3e31892af53eb4306b/Butcher%2C%20J%20C%20-%20Numerical%20Methods%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations-Wiley%20%282016%29.pdf)  numerical methods for ODE I do not understand in the proof how do we obtain the coefficient in the formula $311d$ at $F(t)(y(x_0))h^{|t|}$ from $$\frac{1}{t!}\xi^{|t|}$$ where $t=[t_1t_2...t_k]$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Please, just copy and paste that link into your web-browser if it hasn't started to download the book. I believe that it writes something about security issue if you merely click on it. No worry, no virus is contained in the link. I do not understand what do you need to explain about my question. I just need to derive the coefficient in $311d$ in an undergraduate way to understand it properly. What might be unclear about this coefficient derivation ?

Comment: Sorry, now I give up for new reasons: I am afraid it is beyond my strength to either understand these few pages or read the book from the beginning. I suggest you [put a bounty on your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), to draw attention on it. It would be better received if you [add some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) (in particular explaining the notations).

Comment: Do you understand how the factors $t_i!$ are inherited from the terms in the Taylor-multinomial-expansion? That the node number of $t$ is $|t|=1+|t_1|+...+t_k|$? And that finally the recursive definition of $t!=\gamma(t)$ is used?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I do understand $|t|=1+|t_1|+...+|t_k|$ and also that $t!=\gamma(t)$. Perhaps not how $t_i!$ are inherited nor the rest of your hint. Could you please give yet a bit more hint ?

Comment: Could you please expand your own text in the question with the aim in reading the paragraph, relevant context that you understood and where that understanding broke down. While I'm quite certain that my answer is about what you really wanted to know, and is the bare minimum for this topic, for others my answer may look barely or not at all related to your question text (not the displayed images). This can lead to speedy deletion and suspension.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I've stated my interest in one of the comments above. I do not understand people who are unable to answer my question but down-vote it or even want it to be closed. You have perfectly answered my original question. Shall I delete  the snippets and blindly retype them word by word into the OQ ?

Comment: Comments are considered volatile, they serve as discussion to improve the main text. So the answer to a question in a comment is an edit to the main text and a comment as a notification of the change, and possibly a question back. You could combine your comments as your review to the snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Term-wise integration is easier to justify than term-wise differentiation, but as the context is formal and abstract anyway it makes no difference if you develop the theory on the original (always sufficiently smooth and analytical) differential equation $y'(x)=f(y(x))$ or on its integral form $y(x)=y_0+\int_0^xf(y(s))\,ds$.

#### Form of the expansion

Exploration in the low order terms shows that the expansion of the solution $y(x+h)$ has terms that contain polynomial expressions $F(t)$ of the derivatives of the ODE function. Taking the reduced commutativity of the derivative terms for systems of ODE into account, one ends up with the parametrization by single-rooted trees $t$ (with ordered sub-trees). So in a first view one gets
$$
y(x+h)=y(x)+\sum_{t:\rm tree}h^{d(t)}\alpha(t)F(t)
$$
(see [answer with links for Butchers B-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665979/how-to-extend-this-taylor-series-formulation-to-second-order-ode/4666045#4666045)).
Now insert into the differential equation, using $h$ as independent variable.

#### Taylor formula

For the expansion of the right side as first step consider
$$
f(y(x+h))=f(y(x))+\sum \frac{h^m}{m!}f^{(m)}(y(x))[(y(x+h)-y(x))^m].
$$

#### Multinomial expansion of the power of the series

The powers are a simple multiplication in the scalar case and symmetric tensor products in the systems case. Algebraically there is no difference for this step. Applying multinomial expansion one has
$$
\frac1{m!}(a_1+a_2+...)^m = \sum_{\substack{j_1<j_2<...<j_k\\ m_1+...+m_k=m}}
\frac1{m_1!...m_k!}a_{j_1}^{m_1}...a_{j_k}^{m_k}.
$$

#### Expansion of the full differential equation

Inserting into the differential equation this gives (powers in tuples indicate repetitions)
\begin{multline}
\sum_{t:\rm tree}d(t)h^{d(t)-1}\alpha(t)F(t)
\\=
\sum_{t=[t_1^{m_1},...,t_k^{m_k}]}h^{m_1d(t_1)+...m_kd(t_k)}\cdot
\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{\alpha(t_j)^{m_j}}{m_j!}\cdot
f^{(m_1+..+m_k)}(y(x))[F(t_1)^{m_1},...,F(t_k)^{m_k}]
\end{multline}
Comparing coefficients for the same tree gives the recursions
\begin{align}
d(t)&=1+m_1d(t_1)+...+m_kd(t_k)\\
\alpha(t)=\frac1{d(t)}\prod_{j=0}^k\frac{\alpha(t_j)^{m_j}}{m_j!}\\
\end{align}
The factor $\alpha(t)$ can now be split up into a symmetry term $\sigma(t)$ and a differentiation term $\gamma(t)$,
$$
\alpha(t)=\frac1{\sigma(t)\gamma(t)}\\
\sigma(t)=\prod_{j=1}^km_j!\sigma(t_j)^{m_j}\\
\gamma(t)=d(t)\prod_{j=1}^k\gamma(t_j)^{m_j}
$$
The symmetry term is universal to all iterations that are related to differential equations. The differentiation term is, from a certain point of view, a generalization of the factorial, and gives the factorial for trees that are stems, have no multiple branches.

#### Example implicit 1-stage method

So for instance for a first-order method $y_{n+1}=y_n+hk_1$, $k_1=f(y_n+hak_1)$ one can as well set
$$
hk_1=\sum_{t:\rm trees}h^{d(t)}\frac{\Phi(t)}{\sigma(t)}F(t)
$$
to get the expansion
$$
k_1=\sum_{t=[t_1^{m_1},...,t_k^{m_k}]}\frac{(ah)^{d(t)-1}}{\sigma(t)}\prod_{j=1}^k\Phi(t_j)F(t)
$$
so that $\Phi(t)=a^{d(t)-1}\prod\Phi(t_j)^{m_j}$. For the root $\tau$ with $F(\tau)=f(y_n)$ the coefficient is obviously $\Phi(\tau)=1$

Comment: Good. What kind of object is this expression: $[F(t_1)^{m_1},...,F(t_k)^{m_k}]$ and how it is computed ? We have agreed previously that `[]` is overloaded in the numerical analysis field.

Comment: In Butcher he uses round parentheses. $f^{(m)}(y)$ is a tensor, a vector-valued multilinear form that is symmetric in its linear arguments. I prefer to put the linear arguments in braces $f^{(m)}(y)[v_1,...,v_m]$, in similarity to the tree notation and to make a distinction to the non-linear argument $y$. The tree $[[tau],\tau]$, e.g., then translates directly to $f''(y)[f'(y)[f(y)],f(y)]$. One could write the linear arguments also in multiplicative notation $v_1\odot v_2\odot...\odot v_m$, which then motivates the power notation for repeated arguments.

Comment: Please, is this sum finite or infinite $$
\frac1{m!}(a_1+a_2+...)^m = \sum_{\substack{j_1<j_2<...<j_k\\ m_1+...+m_k=m}}
\frac1{m_1!...m_k!}a_{j_1}^{m_1}...a_{j_k}^{m_k}.
$$
So **where it ends ?** With $a_k$ ?

Comment: It is infinite. But the terms have a degree and there are only finitely many terms for each degree. That is, if the computation is truncated at some degree the computation will be finite.